# Dynamic For Loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dynamic

i understand that to create dynamic for loops, recursive or itertools module in python is the way to go. Lets say I am doing it in recursive.

What I want is

```
for var1 in range(var1_lowerlimit, var1_upperlimit, var1_stepsize):
    for var2 in range(var2_lowerlimit, var2_upperlimit, var2_stepsize):
    :
    :
        # do_whatever()
```

repeat for n loops where n is the number of variables

What I have now is I have 2 lists

```
variable_list = [ var1, var2, var3, ... ]
boundaries_list = [ [var1_lowerlimit, var1_upperlimit, var1_stepsize], 
                    [var2_lowerlimit, var2_upperlimit, var2_stepsize], ...]

def dynamic_for_loop(variable_list , boundaries_list, no_of_loops, list_index = 0):
    if no_of_loops <= 0:
        # do_whatever()
    else:
        lower_bound = boundaries_list[list_index][0]
        upper_bound = boundaries_list[list_index][1]
        step_size = boundaries_list[list_index][2]
        for index in range(lower_bound, upper_bound, step_size):
            list_index += 1
            try:
                dynamic_for_loop(variable_list , boundaries_list, no_of_loops - 1, list_index)
            except:
                list_index = 0
                dynamic_for_loop(variable_list , boundaries_list, no_of_loops - 1, list_index)
```

I did a reset on list_index as it gets out of range, but i couldn't get the result I want. Can someone enlighten me what went wrong?

Comment: This is obviously over-engineering. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And don't try to unpack that into separate variables. If your loop count is variable, just process the tuple `product()` yields dynamically too.

Comment: its a combination study by vary some variable and each variable has its own boundary to observe, thats why i made the variable and boundary into a list to access it using list_index

Comment: And how do you *call* your `dynamic_for_loop()` in the first place? `list_index` will go out of bounds if `no_of_loops` is too large.

Comment: i call it with just    
`dynamic_for_loop(variable_list , boundaries_list, no_of_loops)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `itertools.product()` function to generate the values over a variable number of ranges:

```
for values in product(*(range(*b) for b in boundaries_list)):
    # do things with the values tuple, do_whatever(*values) perhaps
```

Don't try to set a variable number of variables; just iterate over the `values` tuple or use indexing as needed.

Using `*` in a call tells Python to take all elements of an iterable and apply them as separate arguments. So each `b` in your `boundaries_list` is applied to `range()` as separate arguments, as if you called `range(b[0], b[1], b[2])`.

The same applies to the `product()` call; each `range()` object the generator expression produces is passed to `product()` as a separate argument. This way you can pass a dynamic number of `range()` objects to that call.

Comment: I believe you need to unpack the generator you passed to product, i.e. splat it!

Comment: thanks! I am quite new to python so I am still digesting that one-liner you just wrote

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I thought that I would implement this using recursion to perhaps demonstrate the pythonic style. Of course, the *most* pythonic way would be to use the `itertools` package as demonstrated by Martijn Pieters.

```
def dynamic_for_loop(boundaries, *vargs):
    if not boundaries:
        print(*vargs) # or whatever you want to do with the values
    else:
        bounds = boundaries[0]
        for i in range(*bounds):
            dynamic_for_loop(boundaries[1:], *(vargs + (i,)))
```

Now we can use it like so:

```
In [2]: boundaries = [[0,5,1], [0,3,1], [0,3,1]]

In [3]: dynamic_for_loop(boundaries)
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 2 0
0 2 1
0 2 2
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 0
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 0
2 2 1
2 2 2
3 0 0
3 0 1
3 0 2
3 1 0
3 1 1
3 1 2
3 2 0
3 2 1
3 2 2
4 0 0
4 0 1
4 0 2
4 1 0
4 1 1
4 1 2
4 2 0
4 2 1
4 2 2
```